# Sort column in a table alphabetically within a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, alphabetical

I am trying to sort a column alphabetically. This column may have an additional list below it, however, the only factor I am trying to sort by is in the "main-name" class. My issue comes from targeting only that specific element, but sorting the entire tr.

Thank you in advance to anyone who could help!

example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kg2NU/1/

```
<ul class="name-wrap">
    <li class="main-name">Michael Johnson</li>
    <ul class="aka-list">
        <li>Mike</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of table sorting libraries out there. I have seen an example of what your table contains. You might be able to get this one working for you: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/examples.php